# How to add list of missing values in c# list using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, list, addition, items

I have a class like

```
public class MyClass
{
  public float Consumed { get; set;}
  public int RequiredValue { get; set;}
}
```

A list of this class

```
List<MyClass> list
```

already has some items of type MyClass containing the "RequiredValue" say 3,5,6,8 and 10 and corresponding values in "Consumed" property. I find the missing values in the Range of 1 to 10 using the following code:

```
var missingValues = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Except(list.Select(p1 => p1.RequiredValue));
```

I want to add items in the "list" using Linq such that the new items have missing values in the "RequiredValue" and "Consumed" as 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will generate your objects and add them to collection (you don't need to initialize Consumed property, because it already will have zero as default value):

```
list.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(1, 10)
                        .Except(list.Select(m => m.RequiredValue))
                        .Select(i => new MyClass() { RequiredValue = i } );
```